# Notification not Showing from Service

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I searched many other questions related to this topic but found not satisfactory answer also none of them are working for me.
I want to show a continuous notification which should only be terminated by app. But the code i wrote was working a few days ago but not now.

```
private void GenNotification(String title, String body)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.i(Config.TAGWorker, "Generating Notification . . .");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    myIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setChannelId("myID")
                    .setTicker("Notification!")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.floppy)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .build();
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(Config.TAGWorker, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

There is no exception recorded in Logcat, regarding ths. The code is called in onCreate of service. The service is starting correctly i can see in Log cat also there is no exception but notification is not shown. My OS is Android ONE for nokia (PI)

Comment: You have to add Notification Channel for OS Oreo and above. If you don't add then you didn't receive any notification in the devices which have OS Oreo & above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated `NotificationCompat.Builder` constructor which takes a single argument (context); and that won't work on starting from Android 8.0 (API level 26).

So, to solve this:

**Step 1:** Create a [Notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) with the `NotificationManager`

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Notification channels are only available in OREO and higher.
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel
            ("PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID",
                    "Service",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
    notificationChannel.setDescription("Description");

    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
```

Note: changeargument values as you wish

**Step 2:**: Use the non-deprecated [`Notification.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder) class with its two-argument constructor that takes a second argument as the channel ID which you assigned in the first step, where I set it to "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID"

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder
        (this, "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID")
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("body")
        .setTicker("Notification!")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();

mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: It's working like a charm, thanks a lot for this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your strings (title and body) is not null if it's null notification wont show 
Also check that you call your notification channels when you start your service every time if your android above 7.0
Clear notification  when you recall it same id in your case is 1.

Comment: i double checked title and body, they are not null e.g. they got printed in log cat. however i am checking your second suggestion which is clear notification every time.

Comment: Also call your notification channel on service start every time let me know if it's work

Comment: There is nothing wrong about your code remove try and catch and see you get error in logcat also remove  setongoing and setwhen for testing

Comment: Ok testing your suggestions